# Why my RadioButton (in one RadionGroup)can be selected at the same time?

Tags: android-radiobutton

Here is my layout xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="男" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="女" />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

the result is that both radiobutton have been checked
how to fix it?

and if I change the LinearLayout to TableLayout,waht other questions should I notice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get it after many tests!!
The conclusion is: In a RadioGroup,if a RadioButton is set checked="true",you
must give the RadioButton an id (android:id="@+id/name"); If not, the status will not change to disselected with the "checked radiobutton" when you select other radiobutton.
So,don't forget add an id to the radiobutton!

but I don't know how the source code works?